# Analytical solution for diffusion equation with decay

Tags: partial-differential-equations, exponential-function, heat-equation

I am trying to get an analytical solution for the heat diffusion with decaying term. In short:

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = D \frac{\partial ^2 u }{\partial x^2} - ku,
$$

subjecting to the initial condition:

$$
  \begin{cases}
               u(x, 0) = u_1 \text{ for } x \leq \frac{L}{2}\\
               u(x, 0) = u_2 \text{ for } x \geq \frac{L}{2}\\
            \end{cases}
$$
where $[0,L]$ is the 1D domain. Without the decay term, i.e. $-ku$, the exact solution is:

$$
u(x,t) = u_1 + \frac{u_2-u_1}{2} \text{erf} \left( \frac{x - 0.5L}{\sqrt{4Dt}} \right)
$$

My reasoning being, since the decay terms is responsible for an exponential, would multiplying my above results with $\exp(-kt)$ get me the analytical results?

Comment: Short answer is no. Wait for the complete answer...

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1754454/301977)